# Mysql динамический запрос через html форму с множеством фильтр параметров. Выдает ошибку при выполнении 1 и 3 условия одномвременно

Tags: php, mysql, select, form

**Пишу фильтр** для точечного вывода данных из базы MySql. Есть таблица из 20 столбцов (`info_id, info_text, info_data, info_department, info_author, info_leader` и тд). Задача выводить данные опираясь на несколько критериев сразу. 
Для ввода используется форма html с select multiple="yes".

**Пример использования**: выбрать 3-и отдела(`info_department`), 15 авторов (`info_author`), у которых руководитель Андрей Сидоров (`info_leader`), и вывести их тексты в таблицу.

**Суть проблемы**: фильтр выдает ошибку в единственном случае - при выборе 2 условий `info_department` и `info_leader` одновременно. В остальных случаях работает как и должен.
Ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object;

**Debug показал**, что `info_leader` выполняет условие `$check == 0`, хотя должен по логике `$check > 0`.

Подскажите куда смотреть и где допустил ошибку?

```
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $selected_department = array();
    $selected_department = $_POST['info_department'];
    $selected_author = array();
    $selected_author = $_POST['info_author'];
    $selected_leader = array();
    $selected_leader = $_POST['info_leader'];
    $selected_guarantor = array();
    $selected_guarantor = $_POST['info_guarantor'];
    $selected_status = array();
    $selected_status = $_POST['info_status'];

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM info';

    if (count($selected_department) > 0 && $check > 0) {
      $sql .= ' AND info_department IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_department).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else if (count($selected_department) > 0 && $check == 0 ) {
      $sql .= ' WHERE info_department IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_department).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else {
      $check = 0; 
    }

    if (count($selected_author) > 0 && $check > 0) {
      $sql .= ' AND info_author IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_author).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else if (count($selected_author) > 0 && $check == 0) {
      $sql .= ' WHERE info_author IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_author).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else {
      $check = 0;
    }

    if (count($selected_leader) > 0 && $check > 0) {
      $sql .= ' AND info_leader IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_leader).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else if (count($selected_leader) > 0 && $check == 0) {
      $sql .= ' WHERE info_leader IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_leader).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else {
      $check = 0;
    }  

    if (count($selected_guarantor) > 0 && $check > 0) {
      $sql .= ' AND info_guarantor IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_guarantor).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else if (count($selected_guarantor) > 0 && $check == 0) {
      $sql .= ' WHERE info_guarantor IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_guarantor).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else {
      $check = 0;
    }

    if (count($selected_status) > 0 && $check > 0) {
      $sql .= ' AND info_status IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_status).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else if (count($selected_status) > 0 && $check == 0) {
      $sql .= ' WHERE info_status IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_status).'")';
      $check = 1;
    } else {
      $check = 0;
    }

    $sql .= " ORDER BY info_id DESC";
    $result = $connect->query($sql); 
    while($array = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: А как выглядит SQL запрос при выборке двух условий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в логике.
Переменная `$check`, установленная в 1 во время обработки `$seected_department`, обнуляется после прохождения проверки `$selected_author`. Поэтому в `$selected_leader` и срабатывает `$check==0`.
Т.е. по идее, такая проблема должна быть в любом случае, где выбранные критерии идут не подряд.

Еще, я бы предложил немного другую схему создания таких запросов: хранить все элементы `WHERE` в массиве, а потом объединять. В таком случае Вам не надо запоминать, что уже было пройдено, и не надо выяснить `WHERE` ставить или `AND`.

Вот так:

```
$whereArr = Array();
if (count($selected_department) > 0) {
  $whereArr[] = 'info_department IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_department).'")';
}
if (count($selected_author) > 0) {
  $whereArr[] = 'info_author IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_author).'")';
}
if (count($selected_leader) > 0) {
  $whereArr[] = 'info_leader IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_leader).'")';
}  
if (count($selected_guarantor) > 0) {
  $whereArr[] = 'info_guarantor IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_guarantor).'")';
}
if (count($selected_status) > 0) {
  $whereArr[] = 'info_status IN ("' . implode('", "', $selected_status).'")';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM info';
if (Count($whereArr)>0) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $whereArr);
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY info_id DESC";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение с массивом. Всё заработало как того требовала задача.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно предпочитаю в запрос добавить истинное условие, вроде '1=1' и спокойно добавлять через AND больше не о чем не заботясь:

```
$parm=array('info_department','info_author','info_leader','info_guarantor','info_status');
$sql="select * from info where 1=1";
foreach($parm as $k) {
 if(array_key_exists($k,$_POST) && is_array($_POST[$k]) && count($_POST[$k])>0) {
  $sql.=' AND '.$k.' IN("'. implode('","',
    str_replace(array('"','\\'),array('',''),$_POST[$k])
    ).'")';
 }
}
```

`str_replace` я убираю кавычки и обратные косые из пришедших данных, во избежании SQL-инъекции.